# C programming - Finding the necessary number in the array

Tags: c

The task is to calculate how many times a certain digit occurs in the entered sequence of numbers. The number of numbers to be entered and the number to be calculated are set by typing. Ask me if you have got question about code. The problem in finding a match with the number entered in the array.Can you give me hints or instructions, also i think about loop while but i don't know how to realize it please
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, b, n, c=0, arr[30];
    printf("The count of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("The number what is finding: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i < n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]=b)
        {
            c++;
            printf("%d", c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when this code is run? Why is that wrong? Specifically, with sample input, desired output, and current wrong output. "The problem [is] in finding a match" does not actually describe any problem. Anyway, I vote to close as a typo due to using `=` where you should be using `==`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be compiling your code with at least some basic compilation flags. If you do, you will get a heads up that something is wrong before having to run it to find out. It saves **a lot** of time in the long run. Consult your compiler's documentation.

For instance, it would point out that your `if` condition is using an assignment (`=`) instead of an equality comparison (`==`). It should be:

```
if (arr[i] == b)
```

Also, you probably want to print out the total count at the *end* of the program - after the loop is finished. So move the `printf("%d\n", c);` after the loop. (You were also missing a newline which you probably wanted).

Also, `scanf` has a return value - you should check it. If the user enters invalid integers, you want to catch that and handle it properly.

Finally, since you declare your array to be of size 30, you should add a check that the desired length of the input array is no longer than that -- otherwise, you would get a buffer overflow.

Side note: please use more descriptive variable names. Not doing so often leads to confusion, especially for beginners. A small exception to this is for loop counters, like `i` in this case -- its perfectly fine to use a single letter. But consider `b` -- there is no obvious meaning; it should be something like `target` or `to_find`. Also, `c` could be `count` or `total`. As for `n`, perhaps `size` or `length` would be more suited.

Answer (score 0):

`if(arr[i]=b)` it's wrong. x = y is an assignment but you want to do a check. 
To check if two elements are equal you should write `if(arr[i] == b)`.